# What is correct protocol for extended but temporarily unavailable URLs?

Tags: url, redirect, http-status-codes

We have an annual christmas sale on this URL:

```
www.example.com /christmas-sale/
```

In February, when the sale is over, we no longer want the URL to be available.  *However we do want the URL to be available again in a year's time.*

Is there a recommended protocol for dealing with a situation like this?

Should we be using a redirect? I figure not, because we are not specifying a new location for the same resource. The resource has become unavailable (if only temporarily).

Should we be using a 404? That doesn't seem like a good idea, because it will lead to a load of dead links from other websites.  Ones that will be valid again next year.

Comment: Maybe a 503 Service Unavailable? (Though I would hesitate to throw a server error for a page that's temporarily unavailable)

Comment: Yeah that doesn't seem right to me... however I am at a loss as to what would be the 'right' response

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP status code for temporarily unavailable pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642923/http-status-code-for-temporarily-unavailable-pages), but really, why not put op a real page with 'Our Christmas sale will be available again at {insert date}', with a `200`? _Why_ should it be unavailable, if you can create a perfect teaser page on that url? ("leave your e-mail address if you want to be informed when our christmas sales starts", marketing loves that).

Comment: It's for a client. We will probably do something like that, but we haven't spoken yet and I wanted to know which options to offer. I wondered what the experts round here would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don’t you add content on this page?

> The next christmas sale starts 2014-12-01. Subscribe to our newsletter to get notified when …

That way, users can bookmark the sale URL in their browsers and re-visit it again (not possible if you’d redirect).

If you *have* to use a different status code than 200, I’d go with [404](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.5) (emphasis mine):

> The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is **temporary** or permanent.

Of course you could still show content when using 404, so the page doesn’t have to be "dead". But again, I think you should just go with 200. The resource is still there, it just has a different function for your visitors.

Comment: Answers on the linked page (dupe question) would seem to recommend a 503, but I'm with you I'd go for a 404. Presuming there's a requirement for no content.

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox: Yeah, I think using [503](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.5.4) would be wrong, as there is no "temporary overloading" or "maintenance" involved.