# How to indicate a HTML document is a draft or stub?

Tags: html, metadata

Quick question: if I prepare a HTML page as a "draft" or "stub," how would I indicate that in the `<head>`?  A `<meta name="x" content = "y">` tag perhaps, where `x` is {`description` | `keywords`}, and `y` is {`stub` | `draft` | `public`}?

Or perhaps as a `RDF-a` or `JSON-LD` declaration?

I want to specify something like draft, stub ("placeholder") and public (i.e. fully formed, published web page intended for public perusal) as metadata, so that I can programmatically search and retrieve those documents, as I prepare a collection of webpages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider encoding this information not in the pages themselves, but as HTTP status codes. Per this SO question, error 503 is appropriate for placeholder or maintenance pages:
[HTTP status code for temporarily unavailable pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642923/http-status-code-for-temporarily-unavailable-pages)

Another solution would be to include `<meta name="robot" content="noindex" />` only on the draft/unfinished/placeholder pages. Assuming that they have little value to a search engine.

Comment: Thank you: I was not sure if there was a standard or ...  I'll likely add what I described as a `<!-- comment -->` in the `<head>` section.

Comment: Any thoughts on using a `http-equiv` meta tag | https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-http-equiv | https://indieweb.org/meta_http-equiv_status | e.g. `<meta http-equiv="Status" content="stub"/>`?

Comment: I don't know a lot about it, to be honest. It looks like the value "status" is an obscure and little-used extension of that meta tag. I wouldn't expect any kind of software support if you choose to use it, yet you still can use it if you like. Know that "stub" isn't a valid HTTP status code.

Answer (score -1):

The [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/) does not define an element or anything to relay the status of a document. The [`meta`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-meta-element) element is the closest available, and the WHATWG version of the standard points to [their own list of MetaExtensions](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions), including those pulled from the [Dublin Core™ Metadata Initiative](https://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dc-html/).