# What's the suggested/appropriate (if any) REST API status code for an external operation that doesn't complete successfully?

Tags: rest, http

Part of my rest API calls and external service. This service could, of course, fail for any reason. What's the suggested code that *my API* should return to the client?

**500 Internal Server Error** seems inappropriate: why would I return 500 for something that is not "my fault"?

In this specific case:

1. the user try to  place an order
2. If order *is invalid*, **400** would be returned
3. If order *is valid*, the order is sent to the external API (which may fail)
4. The appropriate status code should be returned to the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this post ([HTTP status code for temporarily unavailable pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642923/http-status-code-for-temporarily-unavailable-pages)) it seems like in this situation 503 Service Unavailable is the most appropriate which I myself would also do in this situation.

Comment: Seems resonable to me too. Thanks