# Is there any design pattern to solve the problem of long running code that uses a lot of integrations?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices

Let's say you need to write a REST microservice with a single GET request method.

The only function of this method is to receive and aggregate data from different legacy systems through different types of communication channels. These legacy systems are black boxes for us; we cannot change any of them.

As the number of such systems increases, the execution time of the method also increases. And in some cases, the execution time reaches too long values ​​(seconds and tens of seconds).

Hence the question - is there some kind of design pattern or accepted approach for optimizing such services?

Of course, caching can be a solution to the problem. But what if we only have one highly unique input parameter, such as ID? There is no point in making a cache, since the probability of repeating input parameter is very small. What can be done in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's say you need to write a REST microservice with a single GET request method.

TBH sounds like a bit wrong problem to solve. You need to solve some business requirement and "microservice with a single GET request method" is only one of the tools available to you.

> Hence the question - is there some kind of design pattern or accepted approach for optimizing such services?

There is almost nothing to optimize here - if you need to query some number of 3rd party services then you need to query them. The only thing you can do (in terms of optimization, unless you can fetch all the data and store it locally) is to query them in parallel (based on the tools your stack allows you to) which potentially can reduce the total time of execution to the time slightly bigger then the slowest one (of course if they are independent and you don't need information from one of them to query another).

If the execution time of the slowest one is still too slow or the 3rd party service calls are interdependent then the only option is to switch to asynchronous model - i.e. the service accepts the request via REST (or some message queue) schedules some background work and immediately returns the response (with some kind of correlation id for example). There are multiple options in this case:

- Use [202 Accepted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202) (see also: [Is it wrong to return 202 "Accepted" in response to HTTP GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4099869/2501279)) response with single GET endpoint (which will be polled by client)
- Introduce several endpoints (one to submit the request and another/others to monitor/get result)
- Have a single endpoint to submit the request and use message queue or websockets to notify client about completion/result.

Answer (score 1):

This is already well-baked into HTTP.  Have your GET return a client side redirect (301) to a new target URL which will return a 202 (Accepted, but not ready) until the long-running process is completed.  Server-side, your initial request will kick off the process, spin off a new thread for execution (passing the target location of the delivered response), and return the 202.

For extra points, the 202 can return a status that can be used to monitor the progress of the execution.  This will require keeping some state on the server-side.

Answer (score 1):

I have gone with the similar situations. After research of months, I have used the following practices on my new or old projects.

1. Start replicating data in the database for read heavy operation using kafka. I was using database per service pattern.
2. Move to GRPC instead of REST (services to services communication.
3. All calls were asynchronous.
4. Used stomp protocol in the main service, which is actually aggregating or concluding the results.
5. all of the services was using circuit breaker pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you cant really change anything on the design and your problem is that your endpoint is slow because of the many downstream calls, the only possible optimization i see is if you can make some of those downstream calls run in parallel.

Another option is, if you make calls that you dont care about the outcome, you can have some fire-and-forget requests.

Caching you ve already mentioned.

If you could use non-blocking, reactive frameworks, that would be nice in your case too.